# Passing data in callback

Tags: c++, dll, callback

I have such a callback function (defined in c++ exe app) which is calling from (DLL).
Declaraction in DLL (C++ builder 2009):

```
typedef struct{
INT32      time_stamp;      
INT32      id;              
INT8       len:4;           
INT8       rtr:1;       
INT8       res:3;           
INT8       a_data[8];      
INT8       sts;            
} COTI_CAN_OBJ;

typedef void (__closure __fastcall *COTI_t_UsrRxIntHdlr)(UINT16 count, COTI_CAN_OBJ far * p_obj);
```

When I call this callback in DLL it is executed ok but values passed in p_obj are not correct it looks that are taken from diffrent place (address) than passed.

Can anybody help in this?

This is functions which is called by c++ app (host) in my dll (client) and as a parameter the pointer for callback function is passed:

```
COTI_t_UsrRxIntHdlr local_int_hdlr;
COTI_CAN_OBJ obj;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl UINT32 COTI_InitBoard(
    UINT16 board_seg,
    COTI_t_UsrRxIntHdlr fp_int_hdlr,
    COTI_t_UsrExcHdlr fp_exc_hdlr
    )
    {
     local_int_hdlr = fp_int_hdlr;
     local_exc_hdlr = fp_exc_hdlr;

     fp_int_hdlr(0,NULL);

     return 1;
    }
```

Then in another function I call the callback as:

```
...
     obj.id=0x701;
     obj.len=5;
     obj.a_data[0]=10;
     obj.a_data[1]=20;
     obj.a_data[2]=30;
     obj.a_data[3]=40;
     obj.a_data[4]=50;
 local_int_hdlr(1, &obj);
    ...
```

This is declaration of callback function in c++ app (host):

```
static void CotiRxHandler(UINT16 count, COTI_CAN_OBJ *p_obj)
{
   ...
   return;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show some real code I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

I think has something to do with calling convention. Are you sure you are calling it with __fastcall as default calling convention is __stdcall for windows.

**Edit:**

May be there is data alignment problem. Try solution given below:

Add

```
#pragma pack(push,1) //Add

typedef struct{
INT32      time_stamp;      
INT32      id;              
INT8       len:4;           
INT8       rtr:1;       
INT8       res:3;           
INT8       a_data[8];      
INT8       sts;            
} COTI_CAN_OBJ;

#pragma pack(pop) //Add
```

to your struct declaration.

**Update 2:**

**Change:**

> static void CotiRxHandler(UINT16 count, COTI_CAN_OBJ *p_obj)

to

> static void __fastcall CotiRxHandler(UINT16 count, COTI_CAN_OBJ *p_obj)

Comment: If I change anything in calling convension  then c++ app hangs.
Only such a calling this callback works but passed paarameters are not which I passed. I think that something is with that:
COTI_CAN_OBJ far * p_obj because in c++ app I can see only data passed in p_obj structure but data in this passed structure is not what I set. I think that the problem is about declaration of pointer address but I do not know what.

Comment: I added:
#pragma pack(push,1) //Add
#pragma pack(pop) //Add
but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @CasperGhost has recommended, I would advise you to Debug the code - especially around the DLL/EXE boundaries. See what is being passed when you call the function (i.e. the contents of local variable of `COTI_CAN_OBJ`). Now, have a close look the same variable's content in the called function - see if everything matches. You should use `sizeof` on the data-type (i.e. `COTI_CAN_OBJ`) to see if it is same in DLL and EXE (or DLL).